# Notary support in IBM Container Registry

Tags: ibm-cloud, container-registry, notary

I followed this guide to setup a content trust env and push an image.
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Registry?topic=registry-registry_trustedcontent#trustedcontent_setup
But seems the image is not signed while using "docker trust inspect" to check.
BTW, I'm using free account.
Anything need to enable notary support?

Comment: What output do you see from `docker trust inspect <repotag>`? Did you remember to explicitly specify a tag when you pushed the image?

Answer (score 2):

Notary support is enabled by default, nothing extra is needed. Did you see the `Signing and pushing image metadata.` message when you pushed the image?

Depending on what you want to achieve you could consider using simple signatures as an alternative https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Registry?topic=registry-registry_trustedcontent#registry_trustedcontent_red_hat_sig, it is more straightforward.